# Is it okay to take birth control?

Tags: birth-control

I am a 25 year old girl and just got married. I want to delay my pregnancy in short i don't want to get pregnant immediately. So i am taking birth control pill. Is it permissible?

Comment: And what is your husbands opinion/expectation on this?

Comment: He wants the same.